# How to load / open / suck an repository from GitHub into GitX?

Tags: git, github, gitx

I downloaded Git and GitX for mac and installed it. Now, just for fun, I want to know how I could obtain an repository from GitHub like http://github.com/zoul/Finch.git ??

For me all this Git stuff looks like I have a client and connect to a server in order to get some data from some repository. Like FTP, well not really. But similar.

Just one problem: Where to enter that URL? Is there some field for that? Some hidden command? I did manage to create a new project / repository on my mac, but now I have an empty window and no option to suck down that code from GitHub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) operation. It creates a local copy of (clones) a specified repository.

The very most basic form of its syntax is as follows:

```
git clone git://path.to/repository/with/project.git somelocalname
```

which will clone the remote repo located at `git://path.to/repository/with/project.git` into a local repository in the folder `somelocalname`.